# Character class subtraction

Tags: java, regex

I'm using a specific pattern in attempt to get a sentence without the punctuation.
I have this:

```
 p = Pattern.compile("[\\p{Punct}\\s]+");
 String[] all = p.split("int a = 4;");
```

I get the array

```
all = {int, a, 4};
```

That is great but I want my pattern to also keep "[]" if it exists. for example:

```
String[] all = p.split("int[] a = 4;");
```

and get

```
all = {int,[], a, 4};
```

That is the only change thing I want the pattern to add the "[]" nothing else.
Any way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[[\\p{Punct}&&[^\\[\\]]]\\s]+");
```

The `[` and `]` characters are considered as punctuation characters. This regex will exclude them when splitting the string.

Comment: Thanks :) it words great!

Comment: I'm trying to add the char " (/") so it won't take that off as well... I tried a few options but it's not working for me.

Comment: No matter I got it! :)